# NonUniqueObjectException even if the objects are the same

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I just cannot get the reason why it throws NonUniqueObjectException. The NHibernate documentation clearly states, that:

```
saveOrUpdate() does the following:
if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
....
```

So it should throw an exception only if **another** object associated with the session has the same identifier. 
My objects have their Equals and GetHashCode overridden (_idCopy is used for another scenario and is always null for my case):

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as SimplePersistantEqualSupported);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (_idCopy != null)
        {
            return _idCopy.GetHashCode();
        }

        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(SimplePersistantEqualSupported other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (_idCopy != null)
        {
            // User _idCopy instead of id.
            if (!IsTransientIdCopy(this) && !IsTransientIdCopy(other) && Equals(_idCopy, other._idCopy))
            {
                return GetType().IsAssignableFrom(other.GetType()) ||
                       other.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType());
            }

            return false;
        }

        if (!IsTransient(this) && !IsTransient(other) && Equals(Id, other.Id))
        {
            return GetType().IsAssignableFrom(other.GetType()) ||
                   other.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType());
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsTransient(SimplePersistantEqualSupported obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Equals(obj.Id, default(int));
    }

    private static bool IsTransientIdCopy(SimplePersistantEqualSupported obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Equals(obj._idCopy, default(int));
    }
```

I know that I have the object with the same identifier in the session. I work with detached objects, and this is how it was intended to be. But as they are Equal - they are not Another objects, they are the same. When I look at the NHibernate sources, I do not see check on .Equals() for the objects - it just throws an exception whenever anything exists in the session with the same identifier:

```
public void CheckUniqueness(EntityKey key, object obj)
    {
        object entity = GetEntity(key);
        if (entity == obj)
        {
            throw new AssertionFailure("object already associated, but no entry was found");
        }
        if (entity != null)
        {
            throw new NonUniqueObjectException(key.Identifier, key.EntityName);
        }
    }
```

When I debug at this point, I can ensure that `obj.Equals(GetEntity(key)) == true` and `GetEntity(key).Equals(obj) == true`.
What am I doing wrong?

I do not want to use .Merge as in the application any object can have it's clone in the session, so that will mean that I will have to change every SaveOrUpdate to Merge.

**Upd.** The object I am trying to SaveOrUpdate has another object as bi-directional many-to-many. So NHibernate walks over object tree, goes `my object` -> `another object that many-to-many` -> `my object`, and fails on that, even though first `my object` and second `my object` are equal by reference!

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate doesn't have to do a equal check there. It already knows that the given entity is not in the session because `StatefulPersistenceContext.GetEntry()` returned null. It did return null because it searches for entries by **reference equality**. So if any other object in the session has the same Id as the given one it has to throw an exception to follow the documentation.

Two objects that are equal don't have to be the same. "Same" is usually used to say that two references point to the same object (are reference equal).

PS: Not related to your question, but it seems like your `Equals` implementation is not safe for comparing proxies of entities that use inheritance mapping (the proxy only inherits the base class so it's not assignable to the inherited class).

Comment: Thanks for replying! But I still do not understand. How should I work with detached objects and keep all the objects in single instances? I though Equals() would solve my problems, but it seems doesn't. For example in my application I have two views with different objects that can be edited, but their object trees have the same objects. I have one view for A, and one view for B, but they both have A.C and B.C - so C is doubled and I cannot do anything about that. NHibernate doubles the object by itself

Comment: @Archeg I don't understand why this is a problem. In my opinion, you either want to have two independent views (each with its own session and entity objects) or two connected views (both using the same session and entity objects). Please describe what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the notification about your comment. For some reason SO didn't notify me on email. I need to have two sessions. That is because of the architecture of my application. We use short-life sessions and detached objects. I would like to change this, but for now I do not have time for that. The problem is that because of this I catch strange problems because I receive two instances of the same object (because I have many sessions)